# Quarkus Junit - Apache's Producer template mocking isn't working

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic, junit5, quarkus

Trying to write junit tests for below service class ->

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MessagingServiceImpl implements MessagingService {

    private static Logger LOG = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessagingServiceImpl.class);

    @ConfigProperty(name = "messaging.amq.jms")
    String jms;

    private CamelContext context;

    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "messaging.source.request-queue")
    String sourceRequestQueue;
    
    @Override
    public void submitSourcePayment(final String processPaymentMessage) {

       producerTemplate.sendBody(sourceRequestQueue, processPaymentMessage);

       LOG.info("Message sent to source request queue");
    }
    
    void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {

        final ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(amqUsername, amqPassword, amqUrl);
        context.addComponent(jms, JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(factory));
        producerTemplate = context.createProducerTemplate();
    }

    void onStop(@Observes ShutdownEvent ev) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Shutting down");
        context.close();
    }
    
}
```

Junit test written in Junit5 and Quarkus1.2 ->

```
@QuarkusTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MessagingServiceImplTest {

@Inject
MessagingServiceImpl messageServiceImpl;

@Mock
ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = mock(ProducerTemplate.class);

@Mock
CamelContext camelContext = mock(CamelContext.class);

@Test
void submitSourcePaymentTest() {
    
    doNothing().when(producerTemplate).sendBody("activemq:queue:source-request-queue", 
"");
    messageServiceImpl.submitSourcePayment("");
    verify(producerTemplate, times(1)).sendBody("activemq:queue:source-request-queue", 
"");      
}
```

}

Getting below error ->

> Wanted but not invoked:
> producerTemplate.sendBody(
> "activemq:queue:source-request-queue",
> ""
> );
> -> at amq.service.impl.MessagingServiceImplTest.submitSourcePaymentTest(MessagingServiceImplTest.java:40)
> Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

In debudding I am seeing mock object (producerTemplate) not being referenced, instead new object is getting created. Any suggestions are welcome. thanks

Comment: I don't see `producerTemplate` declaration in `MessagingServiceImpl`; do you have a  `@javax.enterprise.inject.Produces` for a `ProducerTemplate` bean? If not, mocking doesn't work because there is no bean to mock.
I'm pretty new to CDI world, I hope to gave you a good advice.

Comment: If you want to use Quarkus and Camel, you should consider using Camel Quarkus https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus

Comment: BTW no need to call the `mock` method to initialize a field annotated with `@Mock`, it will be automatically done by the Mockito extension.

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Yes I am using, I missed to add it in, I have edited the code. Thanks

Comment: I can't see a the `@Produces` annotation

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci I am not using Produces annotation

Comment: Without a producer for `producerTemplate` you can't mock bean; object created using `new` can't be mocked (I suppose `context.createProducerTemplate()` use the new operator to instantiate producerTemplate)